# Sinon fake server need to test if response after event fires

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon

I am currently creating some integration tests using karma.

Basically, I have an event that fires using sinon fakeserver. But i want to check the response after the event has fired and completed the request to the get request which is mocked.

```
    const event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });
    const endPoint = 'api/test';
    const inputField = document.querySelectorAll('input']; ing

    server.respondWith('GET', endPoint,
    [200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    'test']);

    const callback = sinon.spy();
    inputField.value = 'spectre ';
    inputField.dispatchEvent(event);

    server.respond();

    sinon.assert.calledWith(callback, ['test']);
```

Basically i dont want to add a timeout as this just adds the seconds to the tests

Any ideas would be great

Comment: If you are mocking the server it should respond instantly. Are you sure the server is responding?

Comment: It does respond instantly but it renders an element on the page so we have to wait for that render to appear